# Windows 10 notifications not activating the associated app when clicking on it

Tags: notifications, windows-10-v1903, action-center

I have a new laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 10 Pro (currently running 1903). All is working fine with it except that when I receive (toast) notifications from the Action Centre, clicking the notification doesn't activate the application that triggered it. The notification simply disappears. This has happened since I set it up.

I have read suggestions of enabling apps to run in the background, this is already the case. The problem is purely the app window not restoring or firing up when I click the notification.

I'm not sure if this just a bug in my installation or a more common issue. Any suggestions to fix this welcome.

Comment: Does this happen for all notifications, or just for one app (and which one)?

Comment: @harrymc This is happening for all notifications.

Comment: What happens when you click the notification? Does Action Center close?

Comment: Well if a notification pops up, I click it and it disappears as if nothing happened. The app window doesn't start or restore.

Comment: And if you open Action Center, is the notification there and does a click on it do something?

Comment: In Action Centre, clicking existing notifications works fine and the app is fired up correctly. But clicking new notifications from the popup, will cause it to disappear from Action Centre (as if it has served it's purpose).

Comment: Try to see of the three methods described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-notification-menu-not-working/865b0662-d12a-45f0-bfb6-50e1e6fe90b9) help in any way.

Comment: @harrymc Tried all 3 methods, unfortunately the problem persists. :/

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm I have this same issue.  Doesn't occur on Windows 11.  Same code works fine.  Only issue on Windows 10 21H2 and can see the Activation event isn't even fired.  A dismissed event works ok so its not event firing in general.

Interesting point is that even after the notification disappears after is has been activated, if I go back into the activation center the Notification is there again.  As if the internal OS has also missed the activation event as well and it hasn't really been processed.  Very Odd.

Would be interested to know if this is an OS bug.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).